# Using GIS in outer space

Tags: exogeography

Are there any examples or use cases of using GIS in outer space and in no-earth related use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For imagery, there is quite a lot of information out there:

[High-resolution Atlases of Mimas, Tethys, and Iapetus derived from Cassini-ISS images](http://www.geoinf.fu-berlin.de/publications/denk/2009RoatschEtAl_MimasTethysIapetusMaps_PlanetSpaceSci_2009.pdf) is a journal article that discusses how the authors created mosaics for some of Saturn's moons. Wikipedia has a handful of articles discussing extra-terrestrial quadrangles with lots of external links (There's more that can be search [here](https://www.google.com/#q=list+of+quadrangles+on+site%3aen.wikipedia.org)):

- [the Moon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quadrangles_on_the_Moon)
- [Mars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quadrangles_on_Mars)
- [Mercury](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quadrangles_on_Mercury)
- [Tethys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quadrangles_on_Tethys)

Because of the government shutdown, the USGS references are unavailable, which might have pointed to GIS implementation.